# Google form Integration with saleforce

Tags: salesforce

i have created a Google form . I integrated the form with Salesforce console application by using rest api and Java scrip code backend.
when I fill data and submit the form,the record has to be created in the Salesforce.
My problem/requirement  is  I attach an image file in form and submit  it should populate in the Salesforce record related list  note & attachments. how to do it  please say be any solution I request u all 
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is uncertain, but this post at https://arrify.com/google-forms-to-salesforce-guide/ could potentially be helpful for Google form Integration with saleforce.

Answer (score 0):

I think First you want to take a list of attachment in the apex class.Taking the condition that attachment size not equal to zero and looping through that, by taking each individual object like for Eg:

```
attachment a=new attachment();\
a.ParentId = objectName.id;
 listattachmentname.add(a);
```

Comment: Hi Nalini, welcome to the community! Can you please add more detail to your post for greater clarity and request a code example from the OP to clarify what they are asking? I'll also edit your response to add Code Fences to it's easier to read, please use them in future posts and responses.